# protect private folder htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I recently started to use some MVC patterns 
which make it necessary to have some htaccess settings

I need to deny access to the folder where I store some database passwords
I don't want to use just this :

```
Options -Indexes
```

because it return a message saying forbidden
but i need to redirect to a 404 page , so no one can know the file exists

as an idea I have this :

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteBase /this folder/
RewrireRule ^(.*)$ 404.html [L]
```

but I dont know if it is safe or not

Comment: It's safe this way. You should also set the ownership properties (CHMOD) to 0600 to disable read for all users but owner.

Comment: Please go and do some research as to why _“Security by Obscurity”_ is not a working concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest, safest and cleanest way to do this is to make a `.htaccess` file inside the folder you want to protect and write these three beautiful words.

```
deny from all
```

Additionally you can make a redirection to a 404 page. The `deny`directive will throw a `403` error that you can catch like this:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /404.html
```